# Add packeto-buildpacks/google-stackdriver to spring boot gradle build

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, buildpack

I would like to use the google cloud profiler in one of our projects. Because we use buildpacks to create our docker images, we can not use the standard way of adding the buildpack using a dockerfile.

**So i would like to know: How can i add the buildpack to my gradle build?**

I've created a standard spring boot app and added the buildpack to task

```
...
bootBuildImage {
    verboseLogging = true
    buildpacks = [
        "paketo-buildpacks/google-stackdriver"
    ]
}
```

But if i run the build i get

```
 > Task :bootBuildImage Building image 'docker.io/library/cnb-add-buildpack:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
 
 > Pulling builder image 'docker.io/paketobuildpacks/builder:base' ..................................................
 > Pulled builder image 'paketobuildpacks/builder@sha256:ac9f318cade49b78c229a8bf7858435514b5573177de2a29d2b30bafd5f0b7ec'
 > Pulling run image 'docker.io/paketobuildpacks/run:base-cnb' ..................................................
 > Pulled run image 'paketobuildpacks/run@sha256:41ea15b4d591c2722543009fbf8267a13019ecdc8c6a2b4f437ed83ed29bf72c'
 > Executing lifecycle version v0.13.3
 > Using build cache volume 'pack-cache-fa9655d690f5.build'

 > Running creator
    [creator]     ===> DETECTING
    [creator]     ======== Results ========
    [creator]     fail: paketo-buildpacks/google-stackdriver@5.3.1
    [creator]     ERROR: No buildpack groups passed detection.
    [creator]     ERROR: Please check that you are running against the correct path.
    [creator]     ERROR: failed to detect: no buildpacks participating

> Task :bootBuildImage FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':bootBuildImage'.
 > Builder lifecycle 'creator' failed with status code 100
 
 * Try:
 > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
 > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
 > Run with --scan to get full insights.
 
 * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
 
 BUILD FAILED in 44s
```

Edit 1:

After adding a folder `/platform/bindings/google-stackdriver` including a file named `type` with content StackdriverProfiler i still get the same results.

Edit 2:

After removing that `buildpacks` from build.gradle and adding my project `bindings` instead -> it worked.

So you only need to create a file called `type` with content `StackdriverProfiler` in your project folder `platform/bindings/google-stackdriver` and reference that binding in your `build.gradle`

```
bootBuildImage {
    verboseLogging = true
    bindings = [ "${project.projectDir}/platform/bindings/google-stackdriver:/platform/bindings/google-stackdriver" ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the preconditions for the `paketo-buildpacks/google-stackdriver` have not been met. You read about them here:
https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/google-stackdriver#behavior

In general it requires::

- A binding exists with type of StackdriverDebugger
- A binding exists with type of StackdriverProfiler

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've edited the post. It still not works.

Comment: It seems i'm not the only one with problems to find out how this needs to be done

https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/google-stackdriver/issues/1

Comment: The binding should be all you need. Try removing `buildpacks = [
        "paketo-buildpacks/google-stackdriver"
    ]`. That is telling it to only use that buildpack which won't work. The stackdriver buildpack is in the Paketo builders so you don't need to specify the buildpack to use. Just add the binding files & add the bindings values in your build.gradle file https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.3/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image.customization

Comment: Great. I solved it with your help. Thanks. Can you add please another answer, so that i can accept it.